# Should type redeclare order in a scope be effected by outer scope?

Tags: types, go, scope

I got a strange error message `cannot use []feed literal (type []feed) as type []feed in field value` and after some fiddling and minimizing the source I figured out that this situation seems to produce the error:

```
type user struct {
    Feeds []feed
}
type feed struct{}

func fn() {
    type user struct {
        Feeds []feed // seems to refer to the outer feed type
    }
    type feed struct{}

    _ = user{
        // "cannot use []feed literal (type []feed) as type []feed in field value"
        Feeds: []feed{},
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/gNIGhPwAgl

Is this the intended behaviour or a bug? I've spend some time reading the language specification but can't find anything explicitly stating how type declaration order in scopes should work. It's a bit unintuitive that order does not matter in the outer scope but does in the inner.

Comment: Got down vote. Not sure what't wrong with the question. Seems even one of the authors of the language thinks this is a bit inconsistent but so for good reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so by the language spec.

Quoting the relevant part: [Declarations and scope:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function **begins at the identifier** in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

Types declared inside a function are only in scope from the type identifier (being declared). Before that they are not.

```
type user struct {
    Feeds []feed // This can only be the outer feed type
}

type feed struct{} // new feed type is in scope from this line
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is more or less what rob answered but in a more formal way :)

Answer (score 0):

Found [thread on golang-nuts list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/w40shSAlObk/XQvoxqbJ9v4J) talking about this:

> Briefly, this is because order of declaration matters inside a function but does not outside. At package scope, the symbols are declared in the order that satisfies their dependencies independent of their appearance on the page; inside a function, they are declared in lexical order. A moment's reflection will show why this inconsistency has merit, although it is, well, inconsistent.
>   -rob